# Encoding video from VFR still images

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-encoding

I am familiar with the use of `ffmpeg` to encode video from a series of still images (e.g. a sequence of PNG files) where the images are frames at a constant frame rate.

Is it possible to encode a video where the input images are at a variable frame rate? Essentially I have a series of images (with sequential filenames), and for each image I have a corresponding frame start timestamp. I'm just not sure if there's a way to feed the frame timestamp info to `ffmpeg` for the input sequence.

It doesn't really matter to me in this case if the encoded video has a constant frame rate or not; or even if the encoded frames line up with the inputs (the input is an animation generated from some external data and it's fine if there's artifacts / interpolation between frames).

Since I generate all the images and timing info, I can organize it in whatever way is necessary, that's not an issue at least.

Current `ffmpeg` version is *4.3.2-2021-02-27-full_build-www.gyan.dev*, on Windows.

Comment: See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Concatdemuxer

Comment: @Gyan Oh wow. Totally nailed it; thanks. Found full description of *concat* [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) and description of the `duration` syntax [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Time-duration). Converting start timestamps to durations was straightforward; and performance seems OK. If you want some points feel free to throw it in an answer (if not, I'll just post what I did later). `ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i frames.txt -c:v libx264 -r 60 anim.mp4` for example (needed to disable safe mode so it could accept absolute local file paths [Windows]).